# Selecting an XPath class and text of a span element

Tags: xpath, selector, casperjs

I have an element like so:

```
<span class="myTest">Estimates</span>
```

How do I use XPath to select this? This is what I have:

```
x("//*[contains(@class,'myTest')][normalize-space(text())='Estimates']")
```

Comment: And this is not working?  Do you get an error message? Do you get results which are not what you expected?  Your XPath looks legal at first glance (though I'd replace the second predicate with `[normalize-space() = 'Estimates']` as shorter and more idiomatic); what's going wrong?

Comment: hmmm my casperjs scripts says it can't find that element. I'm also trying this to:  //div[@id='ctl00_cphLeftPanel_mi_estimates_stderrors' and @class='level_2_active']

Comment: Yeah must have something do to the CasperJS not highlighting and finding my element correctly.

Comment: What namespace is the span element in?  XHTML?  Or no namespace at all?

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is actually correct, here's a short test using casperjs master branch:

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.test.begin('your selector is okay', 1, function(test) {
    casper.start().setContent('<span class="myTest">Estimates</span>');
    test.assertExists(x("//*[contains(@class,'myTest')][normalize-space()='Estimates']"));
    test.done();
});
```

Demo:

```
$ casperjs test test-xpath.js
Test file: test-xpath.js
# your selector is okay
PASS Found an element matching: xpath selector: //*[contains(@class,'myTest')][normalize-space()='Estimates']
PASS 1 tests executed in 0.118s, 1 passed, 0 failed.
```